# Настройка дисков

Tags: ssd, hdd, raid, ubuntu

Купил сервер. На борту есть 2 HDD по 3 терабайта и 120 Гб SSD. Все построены как RAID-массивы. К сожалению никогда не работал с массивами. Задача - положить раздел базы данных на SSD диск. Не могу понять как мне смонтировать SSD в определенную директорию.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что у вас есть два пути.

1. Смонтировать SSD в любую папку (используйте /etc/fstab) и в настройках БД указать путь к этой папке.
2. Смонтировать SSD в любую папку, и создать ссылку в папке с БД на папку на SSD. Воспользуйтесь `ln`

Answer (score 1):

Крайне не рекомендую складывать жизненноважные данные на `SSD`. Если вы готовы заморочится на восстановление данных после того как умрет весь ваш `raid` на `SSD`, то умные люди рекомендуют в `fstab` прописывать разделы через `UUID`-дисков. `UUID` вычисляется командой `blkid`.

Пример вывода `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="4b9fb3d5-f1cd-47b8-af0c-3b14fd6ef4ad" TYPE="ext4" /dev/sda2: UUID="A4E0DDE0E0DDB8AE" TYPE="ntfs" /dev/sda4: UUID="d83a7677-8679-49e5-a4cb-4ff63801505d" TYPE="ext4"
```

Далее строка из `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=d83a7677-8679-49e5-a4cb-4ff63801505d /home ext4 defaults 0 0
```